# Render block in a view twig template

Tags: nodes, blocks, 9

I need to render the output of a block within a view / node template (node--news--full.html.twig). Using {{ page.blockName }} does not return anything as {{ page }} within a node view simply returns a boolean (as expected within a node twig template).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module can [print blocks](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#drupal-block):

```
{# Print block using default configuration. #}
{{ drupal_block('system_branding_block') }}

{# Print block using custom configuration. #}
{{ drupal_block('system_branding_block', {label: 'Branding', use_site_name: false, id}) }}

{# Bypass block.html.twig theming. #}
{{ drupal_block('system_branding_block', wrapper=false) }}
```

**Or use the views module itself**

In the views admin UI, you can add a block to the **Header**, **Footer**, or **No results behavior** areas.  Just click **Add** and then select **Rendered entity - Block**.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to get the block to render array in views/node preprocess functions in theme/module and send it to the template through `$variables`.